# Web Forms for Marketers Redirects to bad path

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Why doesn't WFFM use the LinkManager to get the URLs of success redirect items? In web.config, I have the following settings for my site:

rootPath: /sitecore/content/My Site

startItem: /Home

If I browse to www.MySite.com, it works just fine: the Home item shows. Everything I link to using LinkManager.GetItemUrl works just fine.

For my Web Form, I've chosen the success item: /sitecore/content/My Site/Home/Some Directory/Thank You

However, after completing the Web Form, WFFM tries to redirect the user to www.MySite.com/My%20Site/Home/Some%20Directory/Thank%20You (I would expect it to redirect to www.MySite.com/Some%20Directory/Thank%20You)

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem as well, the only way I've been able to rectify the situation is to manually input the path you're expecting in the actual field for the success item.